# Juniper WLA532E without WLC

Tags: wireless-access-point, juniper

I'm tired of low-quality consumer grade wifi boxes that seem to require reboots constantly. I was looking at these Juniper enterprise level boxes. However, enterprise WLANs are typically configured through a special controller box.

Is there a way to use this AP in a standalone home setting without having to pay for a dedicated controller box? I understand that it's possible to run a controller in a VM and I have a server at home on which I could deploy such a VM. However, I've been unable to find any useful info on the juniper website on whether or not such a thing is available for a small number of APs without having to pay extra.